# Does it make sense to have a singleton of an ObservableTransformer ?

Tags: rx-java2

I am wondering if it have a sense to reuse the same ObservableTransformer instance in different compose() operation, kept as a singleton somewhere as example. I don't see any pitfall in the documentation and code (because it simply called the apply method under the hood for new compose use) but every example i find create a create a new one. So maybe I miss something.

Thx for your answer,

Comment: Depends on what dependencies and state that transformer has. If it is stateless and/or only depends on thread-safe globals, it is fine to have one shared. Do you have something particular in mind?

Comment: It has only thread safe globals. I recently see the talk of Jake Wharton about Managing state with RxJava and I want to apply this kind of "pattern" in my API. The consumer provides a stream of request and my API, through transformer (that call Retrofit-like endpoint), transform it in stream of Responses. And my Retrofit endpoints are thread safe. I see in doc that it is recommends to use lift function in this case, but it seems error-prone for non expert like me to apply lift function.